# Idp-Initiated SSO | Validated by salesforce

Tags: java, saml, assertions, federated-identity, opensaml

I am working on idp-initiated authentication to salesforce.com. The generated SAML token is successfully validated from salesforce SAML validation page but when I redirect to salesforce from my idp it redirect me to login page of salesforce instead of log me in to salesforce app page.

My salesforce have current settings are shown in the image.

[image]

I am posting following parameters

*name="SAMLRequest" value = saml token generated*. 
and
*name="RelayState" value = relaystate*

to https://login.salesforce.com/

What is the problem. Why I am being redirected to login page of salesforce. Is there any problem with parameters I am posting alongwith form e.g(parameter name or value incorrect)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the setting is fine. just post this token to sales force ligin URL which they give after SSO settings in a parameter with name="samlresponse" instead of SAMLRequest